# Check if state of sub URL changed with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, url

I want to write a Bash script that asks the user for an URL including sub directory which is static
e.g.

```
test.com/example1
```

But it is expected that after the "example1" part of the URL, any new content can get added anytime, for example:

```
test.com/example1/unpredicted-changeX-Y-Z
```

So it is not known beforehand what will be the change added after "example1" so I want to monitor for any added subdirectories added after the "example1" part.

And that's whats not clear to me. 
I want to check if there are ANY additional subdirectories added after "example1" and store the new change, whatever it might be in a variable.

Hope my question is understandable, thanks for any advice!

Comment: `echo test.com/example1/unpredicted-changeX-Y-Z |grep -oP 'example1/\K.*'` try this

Comment: But how does this help because the "unpredicted-changeX-Y-Z" part isn’t known beforehand, the programs task should be to monitor the address for ANY changes first

Comment: `grep -oP 'example1/\K.*'` is the command you need to run. Assuming example1 is constant here

Comment: thanks, so echo test.com/example1/ |grep -oP 'example1/\K.*' would be the command? Can you explain a little bit what it does?